# Tag categorizer

Tags: data, categorical-data, google, google-prediction-api

I'm using Google prediction API and I need to perform tag categorization for free text. So when I receive a text like "Cant update application" is tagged with #Apps #General #CantUpdate.

My categories exist in 3 different levels.

```
Level1  Level2  Level3      Description

Apps    General CantUpdate   "Cannot update applications"
Network Wifi    CantConnect  "Cant connect to internet"
```

I need to perform multiple tag categorization.
I was thinking in have multiple lines for this.

```
Tag     Description

Apps   "Cannot update applications"
General "Cannot update applications"
CantUpdate "Cannot update applications"
```

Any better idea?